# How to prevent Vim from scrolling buffers when I open split?

Tags: split, scrolling

When I open a new split Vim is scrolling both buffers up despite having enough space.

Here is an [asciicast](https://asciinema.org/a/18333)

This behaviour comes out-of-the box in `vim -u NONE`.

It is really annoying. My guess it tries to keep the cursor in the middle of the screen or something. But even if the both splits end up well above the middle line the buffers are being scrolled up.

Is there a way to turn it off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12897276/151007) which came from Vim's own help docs.  It's not perfect but it is an improvement.

```
nnoremap <C-W>s Hmx`` \|:split<CR>`xzt``
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are wishing that the split would
automatically move the cursor location to the bottom of the screen? If thats
the case then here is a slightly goofy way to handle it.

If you create a function that performs a `split` and then then `zb` on both
halves then you should get the output you desire.

```
function! BetterSplit ()
  split
  execute "normal zb"
  wincmd j
  execute "normal zb"
  wincmd k
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 BetterSplit call BetterSplit()
```

Now if you call `:BetterSplit` you get your nice output. As an added option you can use `cabbrev` to modify how `:split` is handled and trigger your new function directly.

```
cabbrev split<c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'BetterSplit' : 'split')<cr>
```

Now `:split` operates like `:BetterSplit`. One down side is that this doesn't
allow for `:split {filename}` but you could extend this script further and add
in this support.

Comment: I just want text to not move. Why it is doing that in the first place? I thought there is some setting that can improve said behaviour.

Comment: when the window is resized (or split in this case) the cursor is moved to the center of the buffer. Not sure you can do anything besides make split do something different.