# No automatic scrolling when opening splits

Tags: split, scrolling

When using plugins, splits are often created to show something, e.g. a quickfixlist or the taglist. If the split is opened (especially for horizontal splits), the original window is automatically scrolled, depending on the cursor position. If the cursor is on top (`H`), no scrolling is done. However, if the cursor is in the middle or the bottom, the window is scrolled. I personally find this very irritating.

Is there a generic way to prevent this automatic scrolling? A desirable solution would be to not use `H` to get to the top and then open the split (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897276/how-to-prevent-vim-scrolling-when-splitting-a-window) or [that](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/how-to-prevent-vim-from-scrolling-buffers-when-i-open-split) solution). Thanks and BR.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: The first link mentions a [new plugin](https://github.com/gillyb/stable-windows). Have you tried it?